# Xpath add a field from an item to another item with a reference id

Tags: xpath

This is the structure of the file I need to import.

```
<channel>
<item>
  <type>image</type>
  <title>title image</title>
  <id>1</id>
  <image_url>url_to_image</image_url>
</item>

<item>
  <type>page</type>
  <title>node title</title>
  <id>2</id>
  <ref>
    <entity>image_ref</entity>
    <ref_value>1</ref_value>
  </ref>
  <ref>
    <entity>category</entity>
    <ref_value>5</ref_value>
  </ref>
  </item>
</channel>
```

In the page item the  tag contains the id of the image item.
How do I add the image url from the image item to the page item?
I'm trying to use

`/channel/item[id=ref/ref_value[../entity/text() = 'image_ref']]/image_url` but it does not work...

What's the XPath expression to not import the image item but just the page item?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
  /*/item[type='image' and id=../item[type='page']
           /ref[entity = 'image_ref']/ref_value]
                     /image_url/text()
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/item[type='image' and id=../item[type='page']
               /ref[entity = 'image_ref']/ref_value]
                         /image_url/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <type>image</type>
        <title>title image</title>
        <id>1</id>
        <image_url>url_to_image</image_url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <type>page</type>
        <title>node title</title>
        <id>2</id>
        <ref>
            <entity>image_ref</entity>
            <ref_value>1</ref_value>
        </ref>
        <ref>
            <entity>category</entity>
            <ref_value>5</ref_value>
        </ref>
    </item>
</channel>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
url_to_image
```

**Update**:

The OP has *implied* in comments that there may be many "page items" and "image items" and that he needs an expression, getting the image url for only a specific page.

**This XPath expression**:

```
 /*/item[type='image'
        and id=../item[type='page'][1]
                             /ref[entity = 'image_ref']/ref_value
               ]
                /image_url/text()"/>
```

**produces the wanted image url for the first "page item" in the following XML document:**

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <type>image</type>
        <title>title image</title>
        <id>1</id>
        <image_url>url_to_image</image_url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <type>image</type>
        <title>title image</title>
        <id>2</id>
        <image_url>url2_to_image</image_url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <type>page</type>
        <title>node title</title>
        <id>3</id>
        <ref>
            <entity>image_ref</entity>
            <ref_value>1</ref_value>
        </ref>
        <ref>
            <entity>category</entity>
            <ref_value>5</ref_value>
        </ref>
    </item>
    <item>
        <type>page</type>
        <title>node title</title>
        <id>4</id>
        <ref>
            <entity>image_ref</entity>
            <ref_value>2</ref_value>
        </ref>
        <ref>
            <entity>category</entity>
            <ref_value>5</ref_value>
        </ref>
    </item>
</channel>
```

**The result produced is**:

```
url_to_image
```

**To get the wanted url for the second page item, we simply modify the above XPath expression to:**

```
 /*/item[type='image'
        and id=../item[type='page'][2]
                             /ref[entity = 'image_ref']/ref_value
               ]
                /image_url/text()"/>
```

**and now the result is**:

```
url2_to_image
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention that I have other ref tag. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the new structure. +1 anyway for your answer.

Comment: it gives me all the image_url. I'm not getting just the one with the id.

Comment: @SydBarrett, Again you have an XML document that isn't the one you provided. With the provided XML document the XPath expression produces the result as specified in the answer. Please, *update* and provide a realistic XML document. Also, please, specify the URL corresponding to *which page* id you want to be produced.

Comment: I tried with the one I wrote and it does the same thing. I get all the images url.

Comment: @SydBarrett, I updated the answer again, constructing an XML document based on my guess what the real XML document might be. Please, do have a look.

Comment: In the second way, I get just the second, because I've a lot of items, a page needs to get just the image_url from image item with the ID equal to the ref_value. I don't need to get all the url or provide each position for each page, I should get the image_url from the item specified in the ref_value. Thanks a lot for your help Dimitre.

Comment: @SydBarrett, If I understand you correctly, this cannot be done in XPath 1.0 because it doesn't have the facility of defining range variables. This is natural to express in XPath 2.0 or in XSLT, where one can use the `current()` function. If you don't use these, then you must evaluate two separate XPath expressions -- one to get the `ref_value` of the wanted page, and a second one -- to use this value to extract the respective image url.